# Copying xsl element from one node to another

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy an element from one node to another.For example, my input xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Institutions>
   <Schools>
      <schoolOne>schoolOne</schoolOne>
      <scholTwo>scholTwo</scholTwo>
   </Schools>
   <Colleges>
      <CollegeOne>CollegeOne</CollegeOne>
      <CollegeTwo>CollegeTwo</CollegeTwo>
   </Colleges>
</Institutions>
```

I want to move  `<CollegeTwo>CollegeTwo</CollegeTwo>` under `<Schools>` node.
 i.e my output xml should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Institutions>
   <Schools>
      <schoolOne>schoolOne</schoolOne>
      <scholTwo>scholTwo</scholTwo>
      <CollegeTwo>CollegeTwo</CollegeTwo>
   </Schools>
   <Colleges>
      <CollegeOne>CollegeOne</CollegeOne>
      <CollegeTwo>CollegeTwo</CollegeTwo>
   </Colleges>
</Institutions>
```

Any help in achieving this is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I tried with the following code and it is not working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//Colleges/CollegeTwo" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  A good start would be to search for any of the thousands of questions on this site that have answers based on the "identity transformation".

Comment: you did not move the node, you copied it.

Comment: If you want to *move* the element `<CollegeTwo>` to `<Schools>`, then your expected output does not reflect that. Also, what's special about `<CollegeTwo>`? Why would you want to move that but keep `<CollegeOne>` in where it is? I.e., what's the *rule* behind that change?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: What you used over there is called the identity transform. Search for that and you'll find plenty of examples on how to customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started off on the right track by including the identity transform

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own this will copy nodes as-is, which means you only need to write templates for nodes you wish to change (XSLT will give priority to templates that match specific elements)

In your case, you want to add a new child to the **Schools** element, so you need to change your second template to match this element (Matching on `/` as you currently do will match the document node, which is not what you want in this case).

```
 <xsl:template match="Schools">
```

You've already got code to copy the **CollegeTwo** element, but you will also need to ensure the existing child nodes of **Schools** get copied across too at this point. (**xsl:copy** copies the current node, but not its attribute or children).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Schools">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//Colleges/CollegeTwo" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```